# How do I populate the same column using the text parameters from other columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a macro document that pulls information from several columns and places that information in assigned buckets in one specific column.

I made the first portion of the code work where it populated no recovery required into the selected column but I do not think it accurately populated the results and I cannot get the second if statement to run.

```
Sub DecisionTree()


Dim cell As Range
Dim Member_state As String
Dim NO_DR As String

NO_DR = "No Recovery Required"


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 14000 'ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="D").Value = "Arkansas" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="K").Value = NO_DR
    Else
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="E").Value = 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="K").Value = "One"
        End If

    End If
Next

End Sub


I would like answers for why my if statements are not properly calculating and how I can add other if statements to populate the same column
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see I only ajusted your code a bit and used `ElseIf` but your code should work. This is how you could escalate your criterias:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DecisionTree()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Member_state As String
    Dim NO_DR As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'Declare and use worksheet/workbook references

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName") 'change this to the name of the worksheet you are working on

    NO_DR = "No Recovery Required"

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long 'always long, in case your data exceeds 32k rows and anyways working with 32bits will force it to long.
    With ws 'this will allow you to use the reference without writting it
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'this calculate the last row with data, in this case on column A (1)
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Cells(i, "D") = "Arkansas" Then 'You don't need to write rowindex and column index, just their values.
                .Cells(i, "K") = NO_DR 'also, you don't need to specify .Value to change it's value
            ElseIf .Cells(i, "E") = 1 Then 'You can use ElseIf statement instead using else, so you can use as many as you need
                .Cells(i, "K") = "One"
            ElseIf .Cells(i, "J") = "Cat" Then 'another statement
                .Cells(i, "K") = "Cat"'Your code
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad It helped @RyanColeman if you need further help just ask. If this worked for you, consider to mark this as an answer so others may find it.

Comment: What I wrote was just an example... You can use it to fill all your needs.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show me your new code @RyanColeman?

Comment: I added it as an answer to this post. I apologize for all of the back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing an error that the object range failed after changing some of the content and a type mismatch for "YES". ElseIf .Cells(i, "EP") = True Then 'You can use ElseIf statement (issue line)

Sub DecisionTree()

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim NO_DR As String
Dim YES As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet 'Declare and use worksheet/workbook references

YES = True

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Napa Data") 'change this to the name of the worksheet you are working on

NO_DR = "No Recovery Required"

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long 'always long, in case your data exceeds 32k rows and anyways working with 32bits will force it to long.
With ws 'this will allow you to use the reference without writting it
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'this calculate the last row with data, in this case on column A (1)
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, "J") = "8-RTO No Recovery,RPO No Recovery" Then 'You don't need to write rowindex and column index, just their values.
            .Cells(i, "FI") = NO_DR 'also, you don't need to specify .Value to change it's value
        ElseIf .Cells(i, "EP") = True Then 'You can use ElseIf statement instead using else, so you can use as many as you need
            .Cells(i, "J") = "Vendor"
        ElseIf .Cells(i, "EF") = "Boulder" Or "Silver" Or "Nap" Or "Irma" Or "Budlign" Or "Sheffield" Then 'another statement I have to add an if statement consisting of like 6 factors
            .Cells(i, "J") = "Enabled/Present" 'Your code
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: There are many errors there you are not using the variable `YES` you are asking exel if `.Cells(i, "EP")`is `True`. True are for booleans, you want to check if the cell has the value "True", so you need to `.Cells(i, "EP") = "True"` using the double quotes.

Comment: Also, for checking more than one word in a single statement you need to follow this logic: `ElseIf .Cells(i, "EF") = "Boulder" Or .Cells(i, "EF") = "Silver"...` There are better ways to do it, but you need to change that for this to work.

Comment: I originally tried it without the boolean variable and still received an error. Originally I had ElseIf .Cells(i, "EP") = "Yes" and still received a type mismatch.

Comment: If the cell has an error on it, this will throw an error, check the i value to see in which row and if that cell has some #N/A or #DIV0

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah the column does have #N/A present. It's present in both of the remaining columns for the if statement. But would that result in a type mismatch error?

Comment: Indeed, you need to handle these errors with `IFERROR` on the cell